# add field to document mongodb keeping previous data

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a new field to a document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3b1d8c708bf66fc760afb6"),
    "user" : "myuser",
    "password" : "$2y$10$Oh.RKbvf4eT5gozLnD7A0uS5C/k6YluYw0k7uShPD2Elu6FKNBQn2"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3c4e70faa55a342c08c40a"),
    "user" : "user2",
    "pass" : "$2y$10$Oh.RKbvf4eT5gozLnD7A0uS5C/k6YluYw0k7uShPD2Elu6FKNBQn2"
}
```

with the comand

```
db.users.update({"user":"user2"},{"widgets":1})
```

But then the document that matches previous info is lost

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3c4e70faa55a342c08c40a"),
    "widgets" : 1.0
}
```

How can I update keeping the preious data of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $set here. If you donot provide $set then all the fields will be replaced with the provided one in your case user and pass is replaced with widgets. As mention in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

```
db.users.update({"user":"user2"},{$set: {"widgets":1}})
```